# storing the output of a external command to a variable using bactticks in perl

Tags: perl

I am usiing the following code to store the output of an external command in a variable. But when I print the error, I get nothing.

```
$error1 = `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $src_dir $tgt_dir`;
print "$error1\n";  # --> prints nothing
```

The output of the command in `` ` ` `` is:

```
copyFromLocal: Cannot create file/user/file5._COPYING_. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Is there anything wrong in storing the output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/778797/635608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks in Perl only capture standard output. If hadoop is sending the message to standard error instead, backticks won't capture it. See the perlfaq answer for [How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f) for several ways to do it. The simplest is to redirect the standard error file descriptor into the standard output file descriptor with `2>&1`:

```
$error1 = `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal $src_dir $tgt_dir 2>&1`;
```

Modules such as [Capture::Tiny](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Capture::Tiny) are very nice as well.